# How can I let users interact with a toggle button using the spacebar and enter key?

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard-events, togglebutton

I made a toggle button using the label of a checkbox after [this example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8BZvfRD_eU&t=239s). Users should be able to control the toggle button with both their mouse/trackpad and their keyboard. Mouse/trackpad controls are working fine, and users can focus/select the toggle button using the tab key on their keyboards. I can't figure out how to make pressing the spacebar and enter key toggle the button though.

I searched Stack Overflow and tried solutions using event handlers for keypress and keydown events on the input and/or label element to fire the toggleContent function. I also tried a solution that checked the keycode for enter (13) before firing the toggleContent function. Since nothing seemed to work, I reverted to the last working code that allows the user to select the toggle button using the tab key, but not to toggle the button using the spacebar or enter key.

This is my HTML:

```
<div>
     <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" class="toggle" name="checkbox">
     <label for="toggle" id="label" tabindex="0"></label>
</div>
```

This is my JS:

```
const checkbox = document.getElementById("toggle");

const basic = document.getElementById("basic");
const professional = document.getElementById("professional");
const master = document.getElementById("master");

function toggleContent () {
  if (this.checked) {
    basic.innerHTML = "19.99";
    professional.innerHTML = "24.99";
    master.innerHTML = "39.99";
  } else {
    basic.innerHTML = "199.99";
    professional.innerHTML = "249.99";
    master.innerHTML = "399.99";
  }  
}

checkbox.addEventListener('change', toggleContent);
```

Full code and deployment can be found [here](https://github.com/Marjolein-Kasman-de-Jong/PricingComponentWithToggle/tree/main).

How do I allow users to interact with the toggle button using the spacebar and enter key on their keyboards?

Comment: are there no other buttons or input elements on the entire page? Using enter or space to close or open a menu is not really accessible or user-friendly.with exception of the default behavior if you want to check or uncheck a selected element. Try using `tabindex="1"` for the label if you want allow it to be selected

Comment: The label can be selected, that is not really the problem. I'm not trying to open or close a menu either, I'm trying to toggle a button that is basically a checkbox. If that is the default behavior, how do I trigger it?

Comment: For accessibility reasons I'd suggest using a button with the [aria-pressed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-pressed) attribute to create a toggle button. You might also wanna add an [aria-label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-label) so the button has an accessible name.

Comment: @Reyno So you are saying I followed the wrong YouTube tutorial ;-)

Comment: Not necessarily, your approach is fine if you don't care too much about accessibility. Though I'd still suggest adding a label either via the previously mention attribute or by adding text inside your `<label>` tag.

Comment: @Reyno I hadn't heard about these aria attributes yet, so I'll read the documentation and figure out how to use them!

Comment: press the tab until you have the selected element and then you can press enter to click it. Personally, I would state that you followed the wrong tutorial. The tutorial works for hobby programmers on private projects but would never meet industry standards. Most notably by using CSS hacks instead of making sure to use semantics which also are accessible. Accessibility does not only help disabled persons but SEO ratings. Professional quality (a requirement for industry) is not only to make code work but also takes semantics, readability and maintenance into account.

Comment: Modern programmers also would not use `getElement...` anymore but `querySelector` and would avoid to use `innerHTML` as it is comparably slow (reparsing DOM) and open for security risks (XSS injections). In your case `textContent` would have been better.

Comment: @tacoshy I think I am learning a lot today. Thanks!

Comment: @Reyno Your idea is way cleaner AND works better. I implemented it in my project, which is way better now. Next time I have to make a toggle button, I'll choose this approach from the start. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @tacoshy I used your remarks on .getElementByID() and .innerHTML to improve my code. Only just having started my learning journey, I wasn't aware of any problems. Thank you for alerting me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to create a toggle button is using the [aria-pressed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-pressed) attribute. It represents the buttons current state. It the documentation this is described as:

> Adding aria-pressed to an element with a role of button turns the
> button into a toggle button. The aria-pressed attribute is only
> relevant for toggle buttons. It represents the button's current
> "pressed" state.

We also need to make sure the button has an accessible name so we know what it toggles. For this we can use [aria-label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-label).

Using a `<button>` element also comes with the added benefit that it automatically works with the spacebar and enter keys.

```js
const button = document.getElementById("toggle");

function toggleContent () {
  const isToggled = button.getAttribute('aria-pressed') === 'true';
  button.setAttribute('aria-pressed', !isToggled);
  
  if(isToggled) {
    // Show monthly prices
  } else {
    // Show annual prices
  }
}

button.addEventListener('click', toggleContent);
```

```css
#toggle {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 4.4rem;
  height: 2.4rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#toggle .inner {
  background: white;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
}

#toggle[aria-pressed="true"] .inner {
  transform: translateX(calc(100% - 0.4rem));
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle" type="button" aria-pressed="false" aria-label="Show monthly prices">
     <div class="inner"></div>
</button>
```

Comment: The code you provided looks really clear and useful. I'll spend my afternoon reading up on the aria-pressed part and implementing this in my project. Thanks!